# Search field on generic foreign key field

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to add a search field to the Django admin model `CreditsAdmin` that will allow me to search the email of related customer objects. The `Customer` object has a generic foreign key to many different typed of object all of which have an email.

I've already tried defining the function `customer_email` on the `Customer` object and using it as a search field, but this gives the error `Related Field got invalid lookup: customer_email`

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    @property
    def customer_email(self):
        return str(self.content_object.email)


class Credits(models.Model):
    credits_remaining = models.IntegerField()
    current_period_start = models.DateTimeField()
    current_period_end = models.DateTimeField()
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class CreditsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'current_period_start',
        'current_period_end',
        'customer_name',
        'credits_remaining',
    )

    search_fields = ('customer__customer_email',)
```

I'd like to be able to search the emails of related generic objects on the `Customer` model from the `CreditsAdmin` interface. In particular, one of the content_types that the customer objects relate to is django's `auth.User` model, but there are also others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use property in search_fields, because it looks for columns in database level.

[GenericRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation) might be a solution. You can create fields in related(by content type) models. For example:

```
class CntObject(models.Model):
    customers = GenericRelation(Customer, related_query_name='cnt_objects')
```

And in admin panel for Credits:

```
class CreditsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = (
    'current_period_start',
    'current_period_end',
    'customer_name',
    'credits_remaining',
)

search_fields = ('customer__cnt_objects__email',)
```

There is a not best thing with this answer. You must be sure that all related content_objects will have email field. May be issues with performance, didn't test it.

Other solution might be, your custom get_search_results method in admin class.

Comment: Since I am using the django User model directly, it is not possible to add the GenericRelation. Overriding get_search_results was the way to go

Comment: @unstarreren8271 mind sharing your solution with get_search_results?